# Struts framework will automatically convert String to Enum using setter method

Tags: java, jsp, enums, struts2

I have a enum class as below:

```
public enum Sample {
    A("a"),
    B("b"),
    C("c");
    private String abc;
    Sample(String abc) {
        this.abc = abc;
    }
    public static Sample safeValueOf(String abc) {
        for (Sample value : values()) {
            if (value.name().equalsIgnoreCase(abc)) {
                return value;
            }
        }
        return C;
    }
    public String getAbc() {
        return abc;
    }
}
```

in action class I have added a property as below:

```
public class SimpleAction {
    private String sample;
    //getters and setters
}
```

I jsp I am taking the fields ID as sample (property in action class). and getting the value from UI as below:

```
Sample.safeValueOf(getSample());
```

I read somewhere that "Struts framework will automatically convert String to Enum using setter method". So, is there any way to set and get the value with Enum type from form?

How do I get the form value as Enum property in Action class?

Comment: @Roman C: This is not a duplicate question. I need to read the value from JSP not as String but as Enum value.

Comment: It makes no difference. Clarify your question, as far as it's written it's off-topic, I have closed it as duplicate because you already posted a question like that.

Comment: I the previous question i could not able to get the value from UI to action class. And in here, I need the UI field value to get as Enum directly without any conversion.

Comment: It's nothing more than tautology...